# MVVM pattern in javascript who is responsible for what

Tags: javascript, mvvm

Could you please explain me which object should format data and which object in what format stores data: Model or ViewModel? For example,
I have an input field representing data in money format $1,000.00.
Does ModelView stores "1,000.00" or just "1"? If the ModelView stores "$1,000.00" whether this object or Model converts it into "1"?

```
ModelView: {
    amount: "$1,000.00",  // The input field is filled by MV from this prop
    getAmount() { return formatter.unformat(this.amount); }
}
```

or

```
ModelView: {
    amount: "$1,000.00",  // The input field is filled by MV from this prop
    getAmount() { return this.amount; }
}
```

And who fills the Model?

```
ModelView: {
    amount: "$1,000.00",
    fillModel(product) {  // Product is a Model
        product.amount = formatter.unformat(this.amount);
    }
}
```

or

```
ModelView = {
    amount: "$1,000.00",
    getAmount() {
        return formatter.unformat(this.amount);
    }
}
product = {
    amount: 0
}
// somewhere (where?)
product.amount = ViewModel.getAmount();
```

(In this case and below: where should I place the code `product.amount = ViewModel.getAmount();`)

or

```
ModelView = {
    amount: "$1,000.00",
    getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }
}
product = {
    amount: 0
}
// somewhere (where?)
product.amount = formatter.unformat(ViewModel.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 0):

In MV* pattern, view is to present model. So, in your case, model should store number and leave the formating part for ModelView or View. Because in future, you can show your model not only with $ but also with other units.

Let take another easy example:
When storing time, they usually store "time stamp" which is a number instead of year, day, hour, second.

Why?

Because at one period of time, it can be different by time zone.
By storing a number, you can easy compare it, increase, decrease, transfer, ...

At this time, my time zone may be different from yours, but this current time will be store by a number (time stamp) by stakeoverflow :D

Comment: Yes, I understand that my Model should save plain "1". But I don't understand who should (in what object: V, VM or another) store "$1,000.00" and who should convert it into "1". Do I need a controller here?

Comment: The ViewModel **is** the controller that does exactly that! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM the ViewModel is the mediator between the view and the model. Its tasks are for example

- to update the model/view if the other updates.
- to format the model in such a way that a user can better understand/read the model value, which in your case would be that the model holds an amount in $.
- to do validation of the user input. Meaning, if the user inputs something incorrectly it will not update the model.

In your case the model shouldn't hold the already formated string, because it is hart to use it in your program when you need to calculate something for example.

Here is a very rudimentary implementation:

```js
(() => {
  
  const view = document.querySelector('#view');
  const model = document.querySelector('#model');
  
  
  const viewModel = {
    amount: null,
    toView() {
      return this.amount.toLocaleString() + '$';
    },
    toModel(val) {
      const cleaned = +(val.replace(/[,.$]/g, ''));
      this.amount = cleaned;
      model.innerHTML = cleaned;
    }
  };
  
  const updateView = () => {
    view.value = viewModel.toView(); 
  }
  
  // Init
  viewModel.toModel('1.000.000$');
  updateView();
  
  view.addEventListener('input', e => viewModel.toModel(e.target.value));
})();
```

```html
  <input id="view" type="text" />
  <br><br>
  <strong>ModelValue:</strong> <code id="model"></code>
```

Alternative implementation with a `model` object:

```js
(() => {
  
  const viewElement = document.querySelector('#view');
  const modelElement = document.querySelector('#model');

  function updateModelElement() { modelElement.innerHTML = model.amount; }

  const model = {
    amount: 1000000
  };

  const viewModel = {
    toView(modelValue) {
      viewElement.value = modelValue.toLocaleString() + '$';
    },
    toModel(viewValue) {
      const cleaned = +(viewValue.replace(/[,.$]/g, ''));
      model.amount = cleaned;
      // This is just here to show model changes in HTML
      updateModelElement();
    }
  };

  // Init
  updateModelElement();
  viewModel.toView(model.amount);
  
  // Listen to updates from view
  viewElement.addEventListener('input', e => viewModel.toModel(e.target.value));
})();
```

```html
<input id="view" type="text" />
  <br><br>
  <strong>ModelValue:</strong> <code id="model"></code>
```

If you need more information I would suggestion searching the internet. There are plenty of articles about MVVM in JavaScript. Here is one to get you started:

https://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/

Comment: The answer is exact what I need. Thanks! But I have two more question. Why does the VM hold amount? It have been already held in Model. Why do you write ```toView()``` instead ```toView(val)```? I can add listener on model and when it is changed the event occurs. And then by this event the toView(val) invokes. Relating to attached article: I wrote it that's why I asked my question here))

Comment: I was too lazy to add a `Model` object I'll update the above code! :-) Angular for examples does hold a `viewValue` and `modelValue` inside its ViewModel implementation `ngModel`. So I guess it really depends on your implementation and what optimization you want to do.

Comment: Oh, this time you code is absolutely clear for me. Great thanks! The ViewModel is just a layer between View and Model. Could I say that the full name of MVVM patter is M-V-VM-C (MVVM with controller)? Controller should modify data of Model and function ```updateModelElement()``` is a "simple controller" in your code?

Comment: Usually you do not have an `updateModelElement()` function, because who cares in the view what the model value is ;) You rather should thing of MVVM having specialized controllers (=VM) for every view. While MVC has a control that is not necessary bound to a certain view.

Comment: My pleasure! Please consider accepting my answer! ;-)